# Changing namespace names in MVC 3 applications causes compilation errors in generated files at runtime

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, generated-code

I just started a new project and was reorganizing the source structure including renaming namespaces. After changing a namespace from

```
CRTReadmissions.Web.Helpers
```

to

```
Crt.Readmissions.Web.Helpers
```

I get the error shown below when trying to launch the applicaiton indicating that it can't find the old namespace. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Things I've tried**

1. Clean\Rebuild
2. Manually delete bin directory
3. Manually delete the contents of the directory where the generated file is located

**Error**

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CRTReadmissions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

```
Line 26:     using System.Web.Routing;
Line 27:     using Cassette.Views;
Line 28:     using CRTReadmissions.Web.Constants;
Line 29:     using CRTReadmissions.Web.Helpers;
Line 30:
```

Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\crtreadmission\203bedd5\1b724153\App_Web_login.cshtml.3f4b83a6.wbzlumh4.0.cs    Line: 28

Comment: Did you previously modify the Web.config in the Views folder to include that old namespace in the pages/namespaces section?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I solved the same problem by editing the **web.config** file in the **Views** folder.
Just take a look at the **namespaces** tag.
I hope this will help someone who faces the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Even with the new namespace rename tool in Visual Studio 2015 RC, I still ran into this problem with my MVC 5 project. I was getting so frustrated because I did a complete solution search for that old namespace and it never found it in the web.config file.  I kept checking my index.cshtml file trying to find the old namespace.

Comment: Huge help! Thank you!

Comment: I had the same issue (change name space on the project and stuff stop running). Changing web.config in Views folder solved the issue for me as well.

Comment: Recreated and deleted temp files and such 3 times figuring it was something I missed.  Thank you very much for this comment.

Comment: Such a life saver. I lost so many hours when I renamed my one solution. Thanks

Comment: You saved my hair a big pulling! That's brilliant, although it's weird it doesn't pop-up as an error in VS. Hope they do something about it!

Comment: Emphasis on **in the Views folder**.

Comment: thanks, this helped me out big time.